# Array of very long positive integers in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, long-integer

Afternoon all,

http://www.introprogramming.info/english-intro-csharp-book/read-online/chapter-9-methods/#_Toc362296455

The website mentioned prior displays the question:

> 8) Write a method that calculates the sum of two very long positive
>   integer numbers. The numbers are represented as array digits and the
>   last digit (the ones) is stored in the array at index 0. Make the
>   method work for all numbers with length up to 10,000 digits.

Solution and guidelines then states:

> The reader must implement own method that calculates the sum of very
>   big numbers. The digits on position zero will keep the ones; the digit
>   on the first position will keep the tenths and so on. When two very
>   big numbers are about to be calculated, the ones of their sum will be
>   equal to (firstNumber[0] + secondNumber[0]) % 10, the tenths on other
>   side will be equal to (firstNumber[1] + secondNumber[1]) % 10 +
>   (firstNumber[0] + secondNumber[0])/10 and so on.

Could someone please help me understand what the question is asking.

Am i supposed to be putting each digit of a long int in to an array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the down votes? What was wrong with my question? I don't have anyone else to ask and it's important to me that I understand the question before I proceed to try and complete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the input to the method that you will write will be two arrays. It is a little vague but I'd guess the output will also be an array. For example, the number 12345 will be represented as an array:

```
int[] number = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
```

So your method will need to take two arrays like that, say the numbers 92344 and 22344:

```
int[] number1 = {4, 4, 3, 2, 9};
int[] number2 = {4, 4, 3, 2, 2};
```

And then sum the two numbers as the question states, to output an array like:

```
int[] numberOutput = {8, 8, 6, 4, 1, 1};
```

which represents 114688

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the exercise is to familiarize yourself with arrays. This particular example has you break the long numbers into arrays where the last digit(the ones place) is in the array at position 0, the tens is in array position 1, and so on.

The math piece is simple...to figure out what each digit in the result would be by doing a calculation on each digit. Take the numbers 125 and 248 as an example.

Array1 would be [5, 2, 1] and Array2 would be [8, 4, 2], then you would have a Result array.

To get the ones digit of the result of adding these two numbers together, you would say:

```
(Array1[0] + Array[1]) Mod 10
```

Which will result in 3 (5 + 8 = 13, 13 Mod 10 is 3). Result[0] = 3.

To get the tens digit of the result, you would say:

```
((Array1[1] + Array2[1]) Mod 10) / ((Array1[0] + Array2[0]) / 10)
```

Which will result in 7 (2 + 4 = 6, 6 Mod 10 is 6. 5 + 8 = 13, 13 / 10 = 1.3, but when converted to an integer it is 1. 6 + 1 = 7). Result[1] = 7.

To get the hundreds, you would repeat the calculation for the tens, but up one array position:

```
((Array1[2] + Array[2]) Mod 10) / ((Array1[1] + Array2[1]) / 10)
```

So, yes. You need to put each digit into an array backwards, then loop through them, the first time using the calculation for the ones and every time from there on using the second calculation.